# Como criar um tipo a partir de uma variável em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tipagem

Preciso criar um tipo que, de acordo com o valor da variável, utilize um tipo específico.

Tenho as seguintes variáveis constantes:

```
const NEW = 'NEW_PROJECT';
const DELETE = 'DELETE_PROJECT';
```

O código está funcionando com o seguinte tipo, definido com tipos string:

```
type ProjectsActionsType =
  | { type: 'NEW_PROJECT'; payload: { id: string } }
  | { type: 'DELETE_PROJECT'; payload: { id: string } };
```

Porém quero utilizar o tipo da variável constante no lugar dos tipos strings.

Tentei isto:

```
type ProjectsActionsType =
  | { type: NEW; payload: { id: string } }
  | { type: DELETE; payload: { id: string } };
```

Mas não funcionou; recebi este erro:

> ```
> 'NEW' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. ts(2749)
> ```

Como posso utilizar variáveis nos valores das definições de tipos do TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em nível de tipos, o operador `typeof` retorna o tipo (se presente) do valor de seu operando.

Por exemplo:

```
const foo = "FOO_STRING";
type Derived = typeof foo; // tipo inferido é: "FOO_STRING"
```

Veja mais na [documentação do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html).

---

Cuidado para não confundir com o [operador `typeof` do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), que não opera a nível de tipos, mas sim em *runtime*.